# Can't use jQuery after installing using npm and generating a vendor.js file using webpack

Tags: webpack, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use webpack in an ASP.NET Core application. I've downloaded jQuery using npm and then used webpack to generate a vendor file that I reference in my _Layout.cshtml. My webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendor: ["jquery"]
    },

    output: {
        publicPath: "/js/",
        path: path.join(__dirname, "/wwwroot/js/"),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js"
    }
};
```

The file vendor.bundle.js is generated and is referenced in my _Layout.cshtml page. I load the app and check the source in the browser; vendor.bundle.js is there loaded. So far so good. Now, inside ASP.NET Core view (index.cshtml), I tried adding an alert on document ready:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert('a');
        });
    </script>
}
```

But this logs an error in developer console: ReferenceError, saying $ is not defined. I thought I would be able to use it as it was successfully referenced. If I change vendor.bundle.js to a jQuery CDN, the code works fine.

I'm probably misunderstanding something, can someone please explain what's happening.

### EDIT:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4258

Someone mentioned on this page to add this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

It works, but I don't understand why I need to add this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [provide plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/):

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried adding that also, still did not work after running webpack again to re-generate the vendor file.